# STPPaymentMethod TextField won't accept any programmatic card numbers

Tags: swift, stripe-payments

I have recently installed the pod `StripeCardScan` on my project.  I am able to get it to work correctly, however, it isn't possible to get the `STPPaymentCardTextField` to accept any programmatic inputs, from the card scan or just using a manual `let` statement.  I have googled and reviewed several articles on this, but I feel I am missing something.  I am wondering if I need to set a delegate for the class?

Here is the code I am trying to use to put the scanned card into the number field:

```
 cardScanSheet.present(from: self) { [weak self] result in
        var title = ""
        var message = ""
        
        switch result {
        case .completed(let card):
            title = "Scan Completed"
            message = card.pan
            let cardParams = STPPaymentMethodCardParams()
            cardParams.number = card.pan
            //cardParams.number = "4511554566354474".  <- Even when doing this manually, it still does not take
            self?.addCardView.cardField.paymentMethodParams.card = cardParams
            print("card [pam \(card.pan)")
        case .canceled:
            title = "Scan Canceled"
            message = "Canceled the scan"
        case .failed(let error):
            title = "Scan Failed"
            message = "Failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you still need an instance of `STPPaymentMethodParams` to set the card number programatically. Have you tried following yet?

````swift
let cardParams = STPPaymentMethodCardParams()
cardParams.number = card.pan
let paymentMethodParams = STPPaymentMethodParams.init(card: cardParams, billingDetails: STPPaymentMethodBillingDetails(), metadata: [:])
self?.addCardView.cardField.paymentMethodParams = paymentMethodParams ```
````

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion, I did try that, but used the .card instead of (card).   When I used this code its giving the error: `Missing arguments for parameters 'billingDetails', 'metadata' in call`

Comment: So with the new version of the SDK you need to INIT the line.  Using your suggestion, this is the code I used and it worked.   Thank you: `let cardParams = STPPaymentMethodCardParams()
                cardParams.number = card.pan
                let paymentMethodParams = STPPaymentMethodParams.init(card: cardParams, billingDetails: STPPaymentMethodBillingDetails(), metadata: [:])
                self?.addCardView.cardField.paymentMethodParams = paymentMethodParams`